# How to create a table with columns containing different numbers of lines of text but space evenly

Tags: tables, line-spacing, columns

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24338/how-to-create-equally-spaced-columns-in-a-table-with-centered-number-blocks-whi) but it wasn't exact to my needs.

I have a table which contains two columns. Each column is a list of things, one list has 16 items, the other 24 items. How do I get it so the column with 16 items is spaced so it fills the same height as the column with 24 items and has line spacing to do this?

[image]

Comment: What you try so far? Please provide small complete document, which we can compile, which will show your problem (spreading text in table to the same height?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multirow, array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm} <{\centering} |}
            \hline
            1 & \multirow{3}{*}{2} \\ 1 & \\ 1 & \\
            1 & \multirow{3}{*}{2} \\ 1 & \\ 1 &  \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter, where do my sentences go? Within the curly brackets of `\multirow{3}{*}{2}`?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati Ask @ biajia, I have nothing to do with this answer, I only fixed the markup of the code. But I guess you should replace the 1's and 2's with text.

Comment: I see no 2s, I get there are 6 1s though..@biajia?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati, I ran it well in my computer, maybe you missed some packages.

Comment: @biajia the question is more how do I replace the 1s and 2s with my own data?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati You can just replace the 1s and 2s in the table with any texts of yours.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for two independent columns a table might not be the ideal thing to use. How about placing your text in minipages? You just have to make sure that the height (`.15\textheight` in the example) is sufficient for the columns with the most lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t][.15\textheight]{.4\textwidth}
        first line

        \vfill

        second line

        \vfill

        first line

        \vfill

        second line
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t][.15\textheight]{.4\textwidth}
        first line

        \vfill

        second line

        \vfill

        first line

        \vfill

        second line

        \vfill

        second line

        \vfill

        first line

        \vfill

        second line
    \end{minipage}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the height of a cell using the `\parbox`. Then putting two columns next to each other with the same total height should do it. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\newlength\TableHeight
\setlength\TableHeight{5\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \parbox[b][\TableHeight/3][c]{1cm}{A}\\
    \parbox[b][\TableHeight/3][c]{1cm}{A}\\
    \parbox[b][\TableHeight/3][c]{1cm}{A}
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \parbox[b][\TableHeight/5][c]{1cm}{B}\\
    \parbox[b][\TableHeight/5][c]{1cm}{B}\\
    \parbox[b][\TableHeight/5][c]{1cm}{B}\\
    \parbox[b][\TableHeight/5][c]{1cm}{B}\\
    \parbox[b][\TableHeight/5][c]{1cm}{B}
  \end{tabular}
  \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]